# La imagen cambia de On a Off, pero no viceversa

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Creé un botón que cambia el sonido de un video, y quisiera que también cambie la imagen de acuerdo al sonido. Tengo un problema con la imagen del botón ya que cambia de On a Off pero no de Off a On.

Acá les dejo mi código:

```js
var Volume = document.getElementById("VolOnOff");

function toggleImage() {

    if (Volume.src="imgVolOn.png"){
        Volume.src="img/VolOff.png";
    } else {
        Volume.src="img/VolOn.png";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleImage()"  id="audio-control">
    <img src="img/VolOn.png" id="VolOnOff">
</button>
```

Comment: Probaste con un else if(Volume.src="img/VolOff.png) {Volume.src="img/VolOn.png}

Answer (score 4):

Los operador de igualdad en javascript son dos:

- `==` para comparaciones sin tipo
- `===` para comparaciones con tipo.

Tal como tiene escrito el código solo le va a entrar por el primer if porque la expresión que tiene entre los paréntesis del if `Volume.src="imgVolOn.png"` es una expresión de asignación de una cadena no vacía y como resultado de la evaluación de la expresión resulta en un valor no nulo ni de cadena vacía y el mismo nunca se evalúa a `false`.

Sú código debería corregirse

```
var Volume = document.getElementById("VolOnOff");

function toggleImage() {
  
    if (Volume.src=="imgVolOn.png") { //Comparacion con operador de comparacion de igualdad
        Volume.src="img/VolOff.png";
    } else {
        Volume.src="img/VolOn.png";
    }
}
```